# Need help! Maximum recursion error but I can't shorten the code

Tags: python, function

I got the error: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object from doing the following code with Sigmoid:

```
import numpy
import random 

data = [[3, 1.5, 1],
        [2, 1, 0],
        [4, 1.5, 1],
        [3, 1, 0],
        [3.5, 0.5, 1],
        [2, 0.5, 0],
        [5.5, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0]]

mystery_flower = [4.5, 1]

w1 = np.random.randn()
w2 = np.random.randn()
b = np.random.randn()

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def dsigmoid(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - dsigmoid(x))


for i in range(100):
    point = random.choice(data)

# The weights m1, m2, w1, w2 are going to be represented by z
z = point[0] * w1 + point[1] * w2 + b
pred = sigmoid(z)
target = point[2]

cost = (pred - target)**2
if i == 10:
    print(cost)

dcost = 2 * (pred - target)
dpred = dsigmoid(z) 
dz_dw1 = point[0]
dz_dw2 = point[1]
dz_db = 1

dcost_w1 = dcost * dpred * dz_dw1
dcost_w2 = dcost * dpred * dz_dw2
dcost_b = dcost * dpred
```

I need to be able to define the derivative of sigmoid while still being allowed to use dsigmoid as I need it in my derivative statements such as  dpred = dsigmoid(z) any suggestions?

Comment: The `dsigmoid` function doesn't have a base condition, and it's calling itself with the same argument `x` every time. This will lead to infinite recursion, which is what causes your error.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the help! the defining dsigmoid as    def dsigmoid(x):
    enegx = np.exp(-x)
    return enegx / (1 + enegx) ** 2                worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Your derivative definition doesn't have a base condition to stop the recursion calls (also mentioned by @Miket25 in the comments), and seems a bit awkward too:

Per [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+x+:+1+%2F+(1%2B(e%5E(-x)))), the derivative closed form w. r. t. `x` is:

[image]

You could change `dsigmoid` to:

```
def dsigmoid(x):
    enegx = np.exp(-x)
    return enegx / (1 + enegx) ** 2
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned when you defined the function dsigmoid, you have it calling itself again. That means that every time you call it, it keeps calling itself for as long as the code is running. In `return sigmoid(x) * (1 - dsigmoid(x))` if you want dsigmoid(first argument) to be subtracted from 1, use `return sigmoid(x) * (1 - x)`.

Answer (score -2):

Have tried re-defining the sigmoid function wherever you use it?
so:

```
def dsigmoid:
    return np.exp(-x)/(1+np.ex(-x)**2) #this is the simplified version of the derivative I believe
```

Although your method works for me, are you using Python 3 or 2?
Hope I could help!

Comment: Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Your solution doesn't address the OP problem, that is, exceeding the recursion limit. The code you have provide is not valid Python code.